# How does the computer implement callbacks?

Tags: callback, operating-system, epoll

I already know the general usage of callback. First,I register a "callback function",when some event occur,this function will be triggered(be executed).
What confuses me is how do I know if the event is occur? The solution I can get is polling.Is there a better way to check whether the event occur in less than the O(n) time ?

All right,Maybe the above question is too abstract.A more realistic description is does epoll_wait avoid using O(n) time to check whether the ready file descriptor?

If so, how did it do it? 
Is there a callback mechanism that is different from polling essentially?

Comment: I am confused by this question. You know the event occurred when the callback function gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, but not exclusively, callbacks get called after some peripheral I/O device signals an operation completion by raising a hardware interrupt.  A long chain of stuff involving things like driver interrupt handlers, semaphores, protection ring changes, thread and process context changes, message assembly/enqueueing/requiring/handling/dispatching etc etc then cause your callback to be called, maybe by some system thread, or from a message-handling or signal-handling thread of your own that has to conform to a specific structure or constraint.

So no, polling is generally unnecessary, and unwanted.